# What is the server IP if SQL job initiating an EXE which is on a network share?

Tags: sql-server, email, exe, sql-job

I have an EXE which is on a network share, this Exe is triggered by an SQL job. 
The purpose of the Exe is to send mails.

So if someone asks me what is the Server IP that is sending the mails. then should I say the IP of the SQL database server? I'm not sure of how to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly, It depends where is the SMTP server which is actually sending the emails.
So If the SMTP server and SQL server are on the same machine, then yes IP for both is same.

If you are accessing a SMTP server which is running somewhere else or you are calling some email service provider to deliver your emails then IP of Mail server will be different.

Comment: the later is my case, but if the Exe on the network share is initiating the mail then will that IP be considered?

Comment: No matter where are you triggering the process from. So for you IPs of mail server and sql server will be different.